# DDD and LookUp tables

Tags: c#, model, domain-driven-design

**Baseline conditions:**

There is a Bike model with a number of fixed parameters. In addition to the original model parameters, it should be possible to manually add new model parameters.

**Situation:**

Each parameter in the database is represented by the following characteristics:

- Parameter name
- Units
- Parameter value

There are several Lookup Tables in the database. Each of these tables shows the available units of measure.

In other reference tables, the names of the parameters are presented.

The name of the parameter, its value and units of measure should be displayed for each model.

**Questions:**

How best to implement such an approach based on DDD? I do not want to complicate the domain model by dragging into it the approach used in the Database, which should not affect the model at all.

**Notes:**

Initially, before reading the database, I considered that the parameters in the model should be represented by a set of properties, for example:

```
    // Bike model
public class BikeModel {
    public BikeModel(string name, double height, double width) {
        ChangeName(name);
        ChangeHeight(height);
        ChangeWidth(width);
    }


    // Bike model name
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    // Bike height 
    public double Height { get; private set; }

    // Bike width 
    public double Width { get; private }


    public void ChangeName(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void ChangeHeight(double height) {
        Height = height;
    }

    public void ChangeWidth(double width) {
        Width = width;
    }
}
```

However, having familiarized myself with the database, I realized that the "Parameter" value hides a number of characteristics presented in the "Situation" section. It turns out that the parameter can be represented by the Generic class.

```
public class ParameterOfModel<T> {
    public ParameterOfModel(string name, T value, string units) {
        SetName(name);
        SetValue(value);
        SetUnits(units);
    }

    // Parameter name
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    // Parameter value
    public T Value { get; private set; }

    // Units of the parameter
    public string Units { get; private set; }


    public void SetName(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void SetValue(T value) {
        Value = value;
    }

    public void SetUnits(string units) {
        Units = units;
    }
}
```

In this case, the Bike model will take the following form:

```
    // Bike model class
public class BikeModel {
    public BikeModel(string name, double height, double width) {
        ChangeName(name);
        ChangeHeight(height);
        ChangeWidth(width);

        AdditionalNumericParams = new List<ParameterOfModel<double>>();
    }


    // Bike model name
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    // Bike height
    public ParameterOfModel<double> Height { get; private set; }

    // Bike width 
    public ParameterOfModel<double> Width { get; private set; }

    // Additional numeric parameters
    public List<ParameterOfModel<double>> AdditionalNumericParams { get; private set; }


    public void ChangeName(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void ChangeHeight(double height) {
        Height = new ParameterOfModel<double>("Bike height", height, "Centimeters");
    }

    public void ChangeWidth(double width) {
        Width = new ParameterOfModel<double>("Bike height", width, "Centimeters");
    }

    // Add an additional parameter to the model
    public void AddNewNumericParam(ParameterOfModel<double> additionalParameter) {
        AdditionalNumericParams.Add(additionalParameter);
    }
}
```

But how to compile such a parameter using lookup tables?

Comment: The question is not clear for me. If it is about how to create domain model for your existing DB model, than provide DB scheme as well.

Comment: Creating a domain domain model, I tend to maximally abstract from the existing database using the repository. However, I do not quite understand how you can abstract from the database under the existing conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. Just use the repository pattern in your aggregate. 
Please check below to convert from db model to your domain model

```
public static BikeModel ConvertToModel(BikeTable dbTable)
{
    var bikeModel =
        new BikeModel(dbTable.Name, dbTable.Height, dbTable.Width);

    if (dbTable.AdditionalProps != null)
    {
        bikeModel.AddNewNumericParam(dbTable.AdditionalNumericParams);
    }

    return tenantEntity;
}
```

And then you can this for list

```
private static IEnumerable<BikeModel> ConvertToModel(IEnumerable<BikeTable> enumerable)
{
    return enumerable.Select(ConvertToModel);
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<TenantEntity>> Find(string term)
{    
    var lst = await _bikeRepository.GetAllAsync();

    return ConvertToModel(lst);
}
```

You can add an extension method to improve the readability.

However, I think there are few issues on the way you are designing your application. I cannot see any value of using private set as you are trying to achieve immutability. You can restrict the T by adding `where T: struct`, it seems you will be mostly using primitive data types so struct can be a good candidate